# In how many ways can u arrange the letters "No Ideas Help me" with given condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

The N and O are NOT next to each other , the I is directly before the D and the letters EEE are NOT together( 2 E's can be together).

Here's what i tried to do but got stuck

N O together A= 12!2!/ 3! I Before D B= 12!/ 3! EEE together C= 11!

n= A + B + C - |A ∩ B| - |A ∩ C| - |B ∩ C| + |A ∩ B ∩ C|

then i tried to change |B| since we need its complement to do Total - n

so |B| = 13!-12!\over 3!

Then when i try to do A ∩ B it gets complicated. I just need to know if theres an easier way of approaching this.

Comment: How did you get $\frac{12!}{3!}$ for "I" before "D"? Does "I" before "D" mean "I" is directly before "D"? I would interpret that as "I" can be anywhere as long as it precedes "D"... in which case we have $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{13!}{3!}$ ways to permute our letters in this fashion. Since for half of the permutations "I" will precede "D", and for the other half "D" will precede "I" by symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the $I$ is directly before the $D$, we can regard those two as a single element $\fbox{$ID$}$ throughout.

Then there are 12 elements, 3 identical, giving $\frac{12!}{3!}$ basic permutations. However a certain number are forbidden, which are those containing $\fbox{$NO$}$, $\fbox{$ON$}$ and $\fbox{$EEE$}$. These arise in $\frac{11!}{3!}$, $\frac{11!}{3!}$ and $10!$ ways, with $2\cdot9!$ arrangements having both problems.

By [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we get the final count of 
$$\frac{12!}{3!} - 2\frac{11!}{3!} - 10! + 2\cdot9!$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this problem down.

First let's think about our $E$'s. When we put all of our $E$'s down we see that there are four slots created _$E$_$E$_$E$_ and we can fix our $E$'s here since the order doesn't matter (since each $E$ is the same). Now we have two slots that must have *at least* one element in them so that no $E$ is next to another $E$. We label our slots $(x_1)E(x_2)E(x_3)E(x_4)$ and treat this as an integer solution involving our remaining letters. That is $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ with $x_2 \geq 1$ and $x_3\geq 1$. This gives $x_1+x_2\prime + x_3\prime + x_4 = 8$. By stars and bars there are thus $\binom{4-1+8}{8}$ ways to place our remaining elements. But before we place our remaining elements we must arrange them.

Let's look at how we can arrange our remaining letters without our $E$'s. We have $10!$ total arrangements of our remaining letters. For those where $N$ and $O$ are together we have $9!\cdot 2!$. We see that half of these permutations will have $D$ before $I$, and the other half will have $I$ before $D$ by symmetry. Thus we subtract out all arrangements with $N$ and $O$ together or with $D$ before $I$.

Thus our solution is

$$\left(10!-\left(9!\cdot 2! + 10! \cdot \frac{1}{2} - 9!\cdot 2! \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\cdot \binom{11}{8}.$$